# Merge data from nested array into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a dataset that looks like below, (second code). I want to merge all my data to one big object, see example below. I tried to do it with a forEach, but I'm not getting the right results back.

What I want to achieve:

```
 var arr2 = [{
        "date": "20170314",
        "steps": 620,
        "nutrition.calories": 1634,
        "nutrition.fat.total": 57.22602462768555,
        "nutrition.protein": 188.070068359375,
        "nutrition.carbs.total": 83.85400390625
      }, {
        "date": "20170314",
        "steps": 620,
        "nutrition.calories": 1634,
        "nutrition.fat.total": 57.22602462768555,
        "nutrition.protein": 188.070068359375,
        "nutrition.carbs.total": 83.85400390625
      }]
```

This is how my current array looks like:

```
var array = [
  {
    "type": "steps",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 1031,
        "unit": "count"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 620,
        "unit": "count"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.calories",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "kcal"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 1634.100463867188,
        "unit": "kcal"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.fat.total",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 57.22602462768555,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.protein",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 188.070068359375,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.carbs.total",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 83.85400390625,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone please help me with it. Foreach loop is not working.

Kab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the first Data object in the original array has 0 values for every property except for the step, if that is correct for the output array not the answer that you originally provided than this could be the solution:

```
var originalArray = [
  {
    "type": "steps",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 1031,
        "unit": "count"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 620,
        "unit": "count"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.calories",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "kcal"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 1634.100463867188,
        "unit": "kcal"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.fat.total",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 57.22602462768555,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.protein",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 188.070068359375,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "nutrition.carbs.total",
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2017-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 0,
        "unit": "g"
      }, {
        "startDate": "2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        "value": 83.85400390625,
        "unit": "g"
      }
    ]
  }
]

var res = originalArray.reduce(function(result, obj){
  obj.data.forEach(function(dataObj, index){
    if(!result[index]){
      result[index] = {
        date: dataObj.startDate.split('T')[0].split('-').join('')
       }
    }
    result[index][obj.type] = dataObj.value;
  })

  return result;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ilija, I couldn't apply the correct formatting from the mobile website.

Comment: @kabus: Accept and Upvote if the solution works for you. No need for thank you comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some constrains.

For instance, should the data be attributed to the `startDate` or `endDate`?

Following an assumption of attributing to the `endDate`, I think this might help you:

```
var models = {};
array.forEach(function(a) {
    a.data.forEach(function(e, idx) {
        if (!(e.endDate in models)) {
            models[e.endDate] = {};
        }
        if (!(a.type in models[e.endDate])) {
            models[e.endDate][a.type] = 0;
        }
        models[e.endDate][a.type] = e.value;
    });
});
models = Object.keys(models).map(function(k){ models[k].date = k.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g, ''); return models[k]; });
console.log(models);
```

which results in:

[image]